# android application size, return 0 when ask for codeSize

Tags: android, sdk, size

I am trying to write a program that will return the application size (codeSize) of the application. I get that we have to go past the SDK for this and I have done so. However, when I try to test my code, it returns 0 for the size. I try different approaches but the value didn't change. here is the code that I wrote

```
package android.content.pm;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    class AppInfo{
        private String appName = "";
        private String packageName = "";
        private String versionName = "";
        private int versionCode = 0;
        private long appSize = 0;
        private long dataSize = 0;
        private long cacheSize = 0;
        private String appPermission = "";
        private String associateProcess = "";

    }

    private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
        : false;
    }

    private List<AppInfo> retrievedInstallApps() throws NoSuchMethodException {
        List<AppInfo> applicationInfo = new ArrayList<AppInfo>();
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);

        for (int i = 0; i<packages.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo p = packages.get(i);
            if (!isSystemPackage(p)) {
                AppInfo newApplicationInfo = new AppInfo();
                newApplicationInfo.appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                newApplicationInfo.packageName = p.packageName;
                newApplicationInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
                newApplicationInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
                newApplicationInfo.appPermission = p.applicationInfo.permission;
                newApplicationInfo.associateProcess = p.applicationInfo.processName;


                //get the application size
                //-------------------------------------

                Method getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
                            "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);

                try {
                    getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, "com.android.mms", new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                            throws RemoteException {

                            Log.i("", "appSize:   " + pStats.codeSize);
                            //newApplicationInfo.appSize = pStats.codeSize;
                            //newApplicationInfo.cacheSize = pStats.cacheSize;
                            //newApplicationInfo.dataSize = pStats.dataSize;
                        }
                      });
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   

                applicationInfo.add(newApplicationInfo);
            }

        }

        return applicationInfo;
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        List<AppInfo> newAppInfo = null;
        try {
            newAppInfo = retrievedInstallApps();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        for (int i = 0; i < newAppInfo.size(); i++) {
            AppInfo app = newAppInfo.get(i);
            /*Log.i("", "appName:\t " + app.appName + " \t\t " +
                    "packageName:\t " + app.packageName + " \t\t " +
                    "versionName:\t " + app.versionName + " \t\t " +
                    "versionCode:\t " + String.valueOf(app.versionCode) + " \t\t " +
                    "appPermission:\t " + String.valueOf(app.appPermission) + " \t\t " +
                    "associateProcess:\t " + app.associateProcess + " \t\t " +
                    "appSize:\t " + String.valueOf(app.appSize) + " \t\t " +
                    "cacheSize:\t " + String.valueOf(app.cacheSize) + " \t\t " + 
                    "dataSize:\t " + String.valueOf(app.dataSize) + " \n ");*/
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: got it. Need to change com.android.mms to packageName